# Passing the property from controller to view not working? or am I passing wrong property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

I'm trying to pass some properties to view but I get wrong one in view. 
Here is the **Model**:

```
public class ModuleDetails {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string KindName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I've done in **controller**:

```
public ActionResult Details(long id) {
    var ownerId = _dbSis.OwnedModules.Find(id);
    var ownerName = _dbSis.Set<BusinessUnit>().Find(ownerId.ModuleOwnerId);

    var module = (_dbSis.Modules.Select(m => new ModuleDetails {
        Id = id,
        ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
        TypeName = m.ModuleType.TypeName,
        KindName = m.ModuleType.ModuleKind.KindName,
        Properties = m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(
        x => new Property {Name = x.Property.Name, Value = x.Value})
    }));

    return View(module.FirstOrDefault());//am i doing something wrong here?
}
```

and the **View**:

```
@using BootstrapSupport
@model AdminPortal.Areas.Hardware.Models.ModuleDetails
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Module <small>Details</small></legend>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal"> <!-- use this class on the dl if you want horizontal styling http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#typography  class="dl-horizontal"-->     

        <dt>ID</dt>
        <dd>@Model.Id</dd>

        <dt>Module ID</dt>
        <dd>@Model.ModuleId</dd>

        <dt>Module Type</dt>
        <dd>@Model.TypeName</dd>

        <dt>Module Kind</dt>
        <dd>@Model.KindName</dd>
        @foreach (var properties in Model.Properties)
        {
            <dt>Property Names</dt>
            <dd>@properties.Name</dd>
            <dt>Property Value</dt>
            <dd>@properties.Value\</dd>
        }       
    </dl>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", Model.GetIdValue()) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ModuleList")
</p>
```

now when I run the program and set the break point in action of my controller I get this
[image]

I can see that there is some Name and Value in property.
but in view I always get Details of First Item no matter which item I select, but the ID is the Id is Id i selected. 
Is it because I'm doing

```
return View(module.FirstOrDefault());
```

How do I pass the correct item and its property to View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the proper item with an Id = some id to display, you need to select the record by Id. in your code, add a where clause to your linq select statment, it could be...

```
  var module = (SbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.ID == id).Select( ....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return the element according to the `id` you can filter with this: `module.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the result of *.FirstOrDefault()* method is default. it means that you get more than one object, but your view has object model, not IEnumerable. Please replace your code as follow for testing
from

```
return View(module.FirstOrDefault());
```

to

```
return View(module.First());
```

If you won't get an error after this, it means that I am true.